# ¿En cuáles contextos se usaban los pronombres reflexivos después de los verbos conjugados?

Tags: historia, pronombres, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

En el español antiguo, en algunos casos los verbos iban seguidos por los pronombres reflexivos, contrariamente a las normas del español moderno. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de en cuáles situaciones se ponía después del verbo y en cuáles no. Por ejemplo, el pretérito  imperfecto en este extracto del primer capítulo de *El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha* está unido con el pronombre "se".

> Con estas razones perdía el pobre caballero el juicio, y **desvelábase**
>   por entenderlas y desentrañarles el sentido, que no se lo sacara ni
>   las entendiera el mesmo Aristóteles, si resucitara para solo ello.

Pero en este otro extracto se puede observar que se utiliza una mezcla de las dos formas con el pretérito perfecto:

> En resolución, él **se enfrascó** tanto en su letura, que se le
>   pasaban las noches leyendo de claro en claro, y los días de turbio en
>   turbio; y así, del poco dormir y del mucho leer, **se le secó** el
>   celebro de manera que vino a perder el juicio. **Llenósele** la
>   fantasía de todo aquello que leía en los libros, así de encantamentos
>   como de pendencias, batallas, desafíos, heridas, requiebros, amores,
>   tormentas y disparates imposibles; y **asentósele** de tal modo en la
>   imaginación que era verdad toda aquella máquina de aquellas soñadas
>   invenciones que leía, que para él no había otra historia más cierta en
>   el mundo.

Así que ¿en cuáles contextos se utilizaban estas formas? ¿Cuáles factores influenciaban  su uso con el pretérito perfecto? ¿Se empleaban con otros tiempos verbales, tales como el futuro o el presente?

Comment: Con el presente se podía usar, pero no con el futuro. Normalmente, el sujeto es tàcito o se encuentra pospuesto al verbo. Además de los verbos donde se observan pronombres enclíticos, también se podría haber dicho: *secósele el cerebro*.

Comment: I do not see this as a clear duplicate since this question is about what used to happen, not what happens now.